# Iterating through struct fieldnames in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

My question is easily summarized as: *"Why does the following not work?"*

```
teststruct = struct('a',3,'b',5,'c',9)

fields = fieldnames(teststruct)

for i=1:numel(fields)
  fields(i)
  teststruct.(fields(i))
end
```

**output:**

```
ans = 'a'

??? Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.
```

Especially since `teststruct.('a')` *does* work. And `fields(i)` prints out `ans = 'a'`.

I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You have to use curly braces (`{}`) to access `fields`, since the [`fieldnames`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) function returns a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of strings:

```
for i = 1:numel(fields)
  teststruct.(fields{i})
end
```

Using parentheses to [access data in your cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) will just return another cell array, which is displayed differently from a character array:

```
>> fields(1)  % Get the first cell of the cell array

ans = 

    'a'       % This is how the 1-element cell array is displayed

>> fields{1}  % Get the contents of the first cell of the cell array

ans =

a             % This is how the single character is displayed
```

Comment: Your answer is incredibly helpful and has cleared up some things that have been bugging me literally for years now.

Answer (score 16):

Since `fields` or `fns` are cell arrays, you have to index with curly brackets `{}` in order to access the contents of the cell, i.e. the string.

Note that instead of looping over a number, you can also loop over `fields` directly, making use of a neat Matlab features that lets you loop through any array. The iteration variable takes on the value of each column of the array.

```
teststruct = struct('a',3,'b',5,'c',9)

fields = fieldnames(teststruct)

for fn=fields'
  fn
  %# since fn is a 1-by-1 cell array, you still need to index into it, unfortunately
  teststruct.(fn{1})
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Your fns is a cellstr array. You need to index in to it with {} instead of () to get the single string out as char.

```
fns{i}
teststruct.(fns{i})
```

Indexing in to it with () returns a 1-long cellstr array, which isn't the same format as the char array that the ".(name)" dynamic field reference wants. The formatting, especially in the display output, can be confusing. To see the difference, try this.

```
name_as_char = 'a'
name_as_cellstr = {'a'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the for each toolbox from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48729-for-each.

```matlab
>> signal
signal = 
sin: {{1x1x25 cell}  {1x1x25 cell}}
cos: {{1x1x25 cell}  {1x1x25 cell}}

>> each(fieldnames(signal))
ans = 
CellIterator with properties:

NumberOfIterations: 2.0000e+000
```

Usage:

```matlab
for bridge = each(fieldnames(signal))
   signal.(bridge) = rand(10);
end
```

I like it very much. Credit of course go to Jeremy Hughes who developed the toolbox.