# MATLAB iterate through nested arrays and search for element

Tags: matlab

I'm very new to matlab and have a question:

I have a file which contains a **structA** . This struct contains than also **substructA1**, **substruct A2**, **substructA3** , **substructA4** .

Each of this substructs contains a variable **myVariable** of 100 elements.

Now I would like to iterate over all this structs and copy all the elements of the variable **myVariable** into a new file so I will have in one row 400 values

I started like this:

```
structA = struct('substructA1','substructA2','substructA3','substructA4');

  for field = fieldnames(structA)
  // How to continoue from this point ?
```

What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

Just use struct2array:

```
structA = struct(... 
'substructA1',rand(1,100),...
'substructA2',rand(1,100),...
'substructA3',rand(1,100),...
'substructA4',rand(1,100));

data=struct2array(structA)
```

have fun

Answer (score 0):

you can assess each substructs by structA.(field{i})
check this link
[Iterating through struct fieldnames in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803962/iterating-through-struct-fieldnames-in-matlab)